# Enable button only if atleast one row is selected in ui-grid angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I have a ui grid with set of rows in it and a button below that.I want to disable button when no row is relected and enable it if atleast one row is selected.
Below is the plunker of ui grid

http://embed.plnkr.co/nAJ6h07ksn1MIYcHpQ0Q/

I tried to disable button this way

```
<input class="button" name="submit" type="button" value="Find Flights"
      ng-click="postdata()" ng-disabled="gridApi.grid.selection.selectedCount !== 0 ">
```

But this it is not getting enabled when a select a grid how can we achieve this

Comment: Check the answer below and see if it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the other way around. So when you select one item, then it should be enabled. So your condition should be `ng-disabled="gridApi.grid.selection.selectedCount == 0 "` which means none have been selected(so disable it).

```
<input class="button" name="submit" type="button" value="Find Flights"
      ng-click="postdata()" ng-disabled="gridApi.grid.selection.selectedCount == 0 ">
```

Comment: NO it didnt worked.In this way,even by default the button is in enabled mode.which shouldnt be

Comment: Are you pushing the selected elements into gridApi.grid.selection? The button might be enabled mode because by default some value might have been set in your code.

Comment: No..by default nothing is selected

Comment: But in your plunkr, I can see that one value is selected

Comment: No I have removed that

Comment: @Vivz2 in my plunker try to add the code snippet which u gave under the ui grid and see

Comment: See this is the link you have given in question http://embed.plnkr.co/nAJ6h07ksn1MIYcHpQ0Q/. open it and see, one item is selected by default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148421/discussion-between-user7350714-and-vivz).